# How to make automatic call with twilio using that will play my custom record when call is answered using C#?

Tags: c#, twilio

I tried this code, which actually made the call to my phone, when I answered I heard some default voice message:

```
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
Call call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall("+97243000000", "+972547000000", "http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice");

if (call.RestException != null)
{
var error = call.RestException.Message;
// handle the error ...
}
```

I would like to upload my own recorded message which will be played when the call made.
The only related thing I found is how to consume the records, but not how to upload one: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording

Can anybody help me with that? I tried to find it on the Twilio manuals, but could not find anything that works with C#

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

You need to replace the URL parameter you've got in the InitiateOutboundCall method with your own URL:

```
twilio.InitiateOutboundCall("+97243000000", "+972547000000", "http://yourserver.com/play");
```

This URL should return to Twilio some TwiML that includes the [Play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verb.  Play lets you specify a .wav or .mp3 file that Twilio should play to the caller:

http://yourserver.com/message.mp3

If you don't want to set up your own URL and you just need static TwiML, you could use a service like twimlbin.com to host some static TwiML for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I got the missing piese of puzzle. Anyway, get the call with "talking about error". I will try to figure it out tomorrow

Comment: I added this URL: http://qb.azurewebsites.net/hubs/play/OrderArrivedMessage.txt which returns the appropriate XML, anyway, the call says that there is an error. What may be the reason?

Comment: I'd start by checking out the app monitor in your account portal: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/app-monitor  This will show you any errors that Twilio logged when i tried to make its HTTP request.  I suspect either your website cannot serve the txt file in a POST request, or its returning the wrong content-type.

Comment: @DevinRader, how can I take the record file after the call using c# api? I cannot find the recordsid from the Call object using client.GetCall(call_sid);